# How do I set the default window manager under Fedora 21?

Tags: fedora, xfce, mate

Fedora 21 comes with the ugly Gnome 3, and I installed XFCE and MATE, but I don't know, how to set either of them as a default X window manager. After I logout from Gnome 3, I don't see any selection from installed window managers.

Comment: If you are using GDM, after a reboot/restart, when you select the user to login, there is not a choice (pull-down, etc.) of Desktop Environments?

Comment: no, unfortunately, not.. at least I didn't find it... Gnome 3 and GDM... really shame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I interpret your question, you want to install [switchdesk](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/switchdesk1.html)

```
$ yum install switchdesk switchdesk-gui
```

and run that.  You can also try changing settings in `/etc/sysconfig/desktop` as described [here](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix1/SysconfigFilesDesc.txt).

If you want to simply try out a different desktop environment at login time, try installing lightdm or kdm (from the fine folks who bring us KDE) and pick one before you log in.

**EDIT**  The advice above maybe outdated.

GDM does not seem to allow you to choose your desktop environment the way KDM and lightdm (and others probably) do.  Using my favourite DM, lightdm, as an example (use sudo or switch to root):

```
$ sudo yum install lightdm
...
$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

It is possible to do this without rebooting

```
$ sudo systemctl stop gdm  # this will abruptly halt your session and take you to a text console
```

Log in as root and then type

```
$ systemctl start lightdm
```

When I change DM, I like to reboot to make sure my changes persist.  If (like mine did) your machine does not boot to a graphical screen, then log in as root and type:

```
$ systemctl start lightdm
```

Both KDM and lightdm allow you to select a DE from a pulldown menu.

If you want to revert back to Gnome's display manager:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable gdm
$ sudo systemctl disable lightdm
```

Comment: I already tried switchdesk...I already installed mate and xfce, but it is not shown in switchdesk: either Gnome or System defaults... and etc/sysconfig/desktop doesn't exist in the filesystem :(

Comment: Thx, John, this worked out :) both lightdm and kdm :) just don't know which to use :)

Answer (score 2):

GDM does support choosing at login time, but it is sort of hidden.

When I type my login, press Return and before I enter my password a small gear appears.  It is a pull-down to choose the desktop environment.

Unfortunately, it is not sticky.  I must do it every time.  If I get my password wrong the first time, it resets to GDM.